# Bidirectional reference in @ManyToMany JPA relatioship

Tags: java, hibernate

I've just found an example of the @ManyToMany relationship of Hibernate on github which made me wonder what was the correct way to implement it. Let me explain better. The use case is very simple: I have a user which can have one or more roles. I initially thought that this relationship was a many to many relationship, but I found this example which confuses me a lot:

Users.java class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Users users) {
        this.email = users.getEmail();
        this.roles = users.getRoles();
        this.id = users.getId();
    }
  `// getters and setters
```

Role.java class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int roleId;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public Role() {
    }
    // getters and setters
```

First of all it uses a OneToMany relationship (and I can't explain why), and second it doesn't have a reference to Users inside the Role class. Does someone know why and can explain it to me? I would have gone with a ManyToMany relationship and I would have put a Set of users also inside Role with a @ManyToMany annotation. [Here the link to the git repo](https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-db-example).

Comment: 1. Probably because the code is wrong. 2. Because they chose to design it as a unidirectional association, and not a bidirectional one. You'd better learn Hibernate from the official Hibernate documentation rather than from random github repos.

Comment: Ok I see, but in these cases what's the best practice?

Comment: I it's a many-to-many, then it should be annotated with ManyToMany. Keeping it unidirectional looks right to me, since there's no reason to navigate from a role to all the users who have that role (there could be thousands of them).